# My Factors are turned into integer during affectation: I don't want this

Tags: r

Have a dataframe (frame 1) with a column (fact) that is composed of factors I have created a new data frame(frame2) as follow:

```
Matching_list <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = nrow(HH))), c("ProIDS", "Pol_Centre", "Dist"))
```

Now when I select some elements from the variable, fact, in the first dataframe and affect them to the new dataframe, all these elements are turned into integers. So, I see integer numbers (numbers that I don't know where they came from) instead the original description in the first dataframe.

Could you please give me some tips, how can I perform the affectation without loosing information (I mean, keep my factors as they are in the first data frame)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: A) A `factor` is internally stored as integer . In that sense you din't lose any information. B) A `matrix` can only hold data of one type.  If you want mixed columns you should use `list`s (or `data.frame`, which are internally processed as list of lists)

Comment: Also: If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). you could make it easier for others to find and test a answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: Thank you guys! I want to share bellow a sample of my code

Comment: for (i in c(1: nrow(Gps_Households))){
  Matching_list[i,1] = Gps_Households[which(Matrix_of_distance == min(Matrix_of_distance[i,]), arr.ind = T)[1],1]
  Matching_list[i,2] = Gps_poll_cent_west_urban[which(Matrix_of_distance == min(Matrix_of_distance[i,]), arr.ind = T)[2],1]
  Matching_list[i,3] = min(Matrix_of_distance[i,])
  Column[i] = Gps_poll_cent_west_urban[which(Matrix_of_distance == min(Matrix_of_distance[i,]), arr.ind = T)[2],1]
}

Comment: But I think the problem is related to the fact that I am using a matrix, I should use a list instead. How can I use a matrix to fill up a list?

Comment: What @dario had in mind (and others too) as wanting was not that you share code but that you share reproducible data!

Comment: One more thing: when you say 'affect' and affectation' do oyu really mean 'add' or 'assign' and 'addition' or 'assigment'?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **completely tentative** solution to your problem (as you've not provided any reproducible data).

Assuming you have this kind of data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(fact = LETTERS[1:10])
```

if you look at the variable `fact`'s structure, you will see it's a factor:

```
str(df1)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ fact: Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Now further assuming that, as you say, you have another dataframe, like this:

```
set.seed(100)
df2 <- data.frame(varX = rnorm(10))
```

and that it is to this dataframe that you want to assign some factor *level* from `fact` depending on some condition, and want to get in the output not an integer but the actual factor level, this could be done using `levels`:

```
df2$fact <- ifelse(df2$varX < 0, levels(df1$fact)[1], NA) # if varX < 0 "A" else NA
df2
          varX fact
1  -0.50219235    A
2   0.13153117 <NA>
3  -0.07891709    A
4   0.88678481 <NA>
5   0.11697127 <NA>
6   0.31863009 <NA>
7  -0.58179068    A
8   0.71453271 <NA>
9  -0.82525943    A
10 -0.35986213    A
```

But note that if you now check the structure of `df2`, R has converted `df2$fact`into a character variable:

```
str(df2)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ varX: num  -0.5022 0.1315 -0.0789 0.8868 0.117 ...
 $ fact: chr  "A" NA "A" NA ...
```